# Place menu item towards left of the title

Tags: android, menuitem

[image]

How can i place the search icon towards extreme left of the title "Restaurants" ?

Comment: Could you please show your layout file? Try to change the gravity values

Comment: :( i'm not able to add the code. Every time its says, looks like your post is mostly code. Please add some more details. It shows me this message inspite of adding "changes" and "short summary". Is there any other way i can attach the code :\

Comment: Edit your question and add the layout. Do not answer your own question